# QuestionAboutCreating IOS SDK in order to hook one app onto another app

Tags: ios, mobile, hook, banner

I got one question, Need help. Thanks.

Question: One App have already been created which will delivered Ads based on data, right now, I want to hook this app to another app but without wrapping the whole App to the second App, which i searched would create a static framework, but not that in that, the second App will just deliver one simple ID,and retain one banner space for showing the upcoming Ads, then in my App-server, It will only return the Ads to the second App.

How to do this ?

Comment: You need to get this re-written to be more intelligible - its really hard to understand what you want. The common way to write some code and re-use it in more than on project is to write a "library" project and include it in other "app" projects. There is ample discussion of how to do that on this site.

Comment: Thanks David, what is .ipa file? what is the different between creating a static framework and create a .ipa file ?

Comment: I don't know what a ipa file is, but I do know that if you create a library project, you can write it once and include it in multiple projects - been doing that for years.

Comment: Thanks David. My confusion is: when you play a radio app, there is always some advertisement coming out in a banner at the bottom screen, but right now, the advertisement is coming from other app,so how can I hook the other app to the radio app so that it will shows the advertisement on the radio app. what is .ipa ad-hoc ?

Comment: You would have to connect them using a network protocol that connects to an external server to do that. There is no inter process communication on ios.